# Operacion booleana en componente HTML

Tags: java, html, primefaces

Tengo un proyecto **Java Web** donde utilizo **SpringSecurity** para garantizar la seguridad y el acceso a páginas por parte de los roles de usuario, **Bootsfaces** y **JSF** para el maquetado web. Pero necesito ocultar ciertos botones y links de acuerdo a los roles con que cuente un usuario (Un usuario puede tener uno o más roles), en el sistema son un total de cinco roles hasta el momento.
Lo que estoy utilizando para no mostrar los elementos HTML es el atributo **rendered** de Bootsfaces, que si se encuentra en falso no renderizará el elemento en el visual. Cree una variable boolean para cada uno de los roles en un JSFBean que son rellenados durante el logueo del usuario.
El problema está en que como un usuario puede tener varios roles y varios roles pueden tener acceso a una página necesito hacer una operación booleana para calcular el booleano final que se encontrará en el rendered.
O sea `ROLE_ADMIN OR ROLE_MATRICULADOR` si esa operación booleana es true el atributo rendered será true y se mostrará el elemento en la página web, si es falso no se mostrará.

Intenté colocar entre los booleanos AND, OR, &&, || y no logro que funcione.

```
<b:listLinks rendered="#{templateBean.role_admin} OR #{templateBean.role_matriculador}" class="notika-main-menu-dropdown">
     <b:navLink value="Gestionar Plan" href="#{templateBean.request}/pages/admin/AdminPlanEstudio.faces"/>
</b:listLinks>
```

Este es el bean donde se les da valor a los booleanos:

```
public void verifyRol() {
        List<String> list_roles = serv_user.findUsersRoles(username);
        for (String l : list_roles) {
            if (l.equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                role_admin = true;
                continue;
            } else if (l.equals("ROLE_SECRETARIA")) {
                role_secretaria = true;
                continue;
            }
            else if (l.equals("ROLE_SECRETARIO_GENERAL")) {
                role_secretario_general = true;
                continue;
            }
            else if (l.equals("ROLE_VICEDECANO")) {
                role_vicedecano = true;
                continue;
            }
            else{
                role_matriculador = true;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Existe alguna forma de hacerlo como describo? O existe alguna forma mejor para ocultar los elementos?

Comment: Hola, el atributo `rendered` debería haber sido `rendered="#{templateBean.role_admin OR templateBean.role_matriculador}"` en lugar de `rendered="#{templateBean.role_admin} OR #{templateBean.role_matriculador}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya resolvi el problema, no sabía que en Java existía algo llamado método con parámetros variables y cree una especie de traductor de operaciones booleanas OR variable. Calculando bien no es necesario realizar operaciones AND y menos combinaciones entre OR y AND, así que funciona para lo que quiero hacer. 
Este es el método que se encarga de realizar la operación booleana:

```
public boolean translateRole_Boolean(boolean... r) {
        boolean t = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            t = t || r[i];
        }
        return t;
}
```

La llamada en el visual se haría asi:

```
<b:listLinks rendered="#{templateBean.translateRole_Boolean(templateBean.role_matriculador, templateBean.role_secretaria)}" class="notika-main-menu-dropdown">
     <b:navLink value="Gestionar Plan" href="#{templateBean.request}/pages/admin/AdminPlanEstudio.faces"/>
</b:listLinks>
```